# How to keep track of how many times a unique condition occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
time  val
0      1
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      1
5      2
6      3
7      3
8      3
9      3
10     1
11     1
```

How do I create new columns that hold the amount of times a condition occurs and does not change? In this case, I want to create a column for each unique value in `val` that holds the cumulative sum at the given row of occurences, but does not increment the value if the condition doesn't change.

Expected outcome below:

```
time  val  sum_1   sum_2    sum_3
0      1    1        0       0 
1      1    1        0       0
2      2    1        1       0
3      3    1        1       1
4      1    2        1       1
5      2    2        2       1
6      3    2        2       2 
7      3    2        2       2
8      3    2        2       2
9      3    2        2       2
10     1    3        2       2
11     1    3        2       2
```

#### EDIT

To be more specific with the condition:

I want to count the number of times a unique value appears in `val`. For example, using the code below, I could get this result:

```
df['sum_1'] = (df['val'] == 1).cumsum()
df['sum_2'] = (df['val'] == 2).cumsum()
df['sum_3'] = (df['val'] == 3).cumsum()

   time  val  sum_1  sum_2  sum_3
0     0    1      1      0      0
1     1    1      2      0      0
2     2    2      2      1      0
3     3    3      2      1      1
4     4    1      3      1      1
5     5    2      3      2      1
```

However, this code counts EVERY occurence of a condition. For example, `val` shows `1` occurring 3 times total. However, I want to treat consecutive occurrences of `1` as a single group, counting only the number of consecutive groupings that occur. In the example above, `1` occurs in total 3 times, but only 2 times as a consecutive grouping.

Comment: @LoukasPap yes it is

Comment: Can you be more specific with the condition?

Comment: Made an edit for specificity. Hopefully it suffices.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain mask by `&` for bitwise `AND` for test first consecutive values by compare by shifted values by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and run code for test all unique values of column `val`:

```
uniq = df['val'].unique()
m = df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift())

for c in uniq:
    df[f'sum_{c}'] = (df['val'].eq(c) & m).cumsum()
print (df)
    time  val  sum_1  sum_2  sum_3
0      0    1      1      0      0
1      1    1      1      0      0
2      2    2      1      1      0
3      3    3      1      1      1
4      4    1      2      1      1
5      5    2      2      2      1
6      6    3      2      2      2
7      7    3      2      2      2
8      8    3      2      2      2
9      9    3      2      2      2
10    10    1      3      2      2
11    11    1      3      2      2
```

For better performance (I hope) here is numpy alternative:

```
a = df['val'].to_numpy()
uniq = np.unique(a)
m = np.concatenate(([False], a[:-1])) != a

arr = np.cumsum((a[:, None] == uniq) & m[:, None], axis=0)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=uniq).add_prefix('sum_'))
print (df)
    time  val  sum_1  sum_2  sum_3
0      0    1      1      0      0
1      1    1      1      0      0
2      2    2      1      1      0
3      3    3      1      1      1
4      4    1      2      1      1
5      5    2      2      2      1
6      6    3      2      2      2
7      7    3      2      2      2
8      8    3      2      2      2
9      9    3      2      2      2
10    10    1      3      2      2
11    11    1      3      2      2
```